# Spring permission on mapping resource

Tags: java, spring, file, mapping

I developing spring application and I set mapping resources:

```
<resources mapping="/src/**" location="/src/" order="-1" />
```

Now I have access for all files inside src folder without loging and that is ok.
Now I try to read all files inside src folder with File Class but now I do not have permission to read files. How to solve this?

```
File file = new File(rquest.getContextPath()+"/src");
file.setReadable(true, true);
System.out.println(file.listFiles());
```

So listFiles() function return null, I think that is problem with permission?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Let's say the context path of your webapp is `/myFistWebApp`. The code will list all the files that are, on the web server's file system, under `/myFirstWebApp/src`. I doubt you have such a directory on your web server. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a permission problem. Your trying to access a file via `r(e)quest.getContextPath()` which is used for web access (not file system!)

If you want to access files in your workspace/deploy location of your project via the file-system, you should use on of the following methods:

```
Resource myData = new ClasspathResource("myData.xml"): - this will be relative to WEB-INF deploy directory
```

or:

```
new File(servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/your-path-relative-to-WEB-INF-deploy-path");
```

I personally recommend method #1

**EDIT**

Your questions suggests that you think your `src` folder is being deployed (copied to the server with your WAR/EAR/Built project, this is usually not true. Normally, the Webpages folder (whatever name you call it within your app) and everything inside of WEB-INF is being deployed. hoping this was helpful.

Comment: Is there some function which can translate realPath("/") to requestContextPath()?

Comment: when I test this in localhost I got this url: E:/netbeans/project/build/web/src/upload/IMG_1696.jpg

 So how translate this link to readable link for img src. Or I must do it manually?

Comment: Refer to the last part of my answer. You should put your "web accessible" files under WEB-INF directory, i.e E:/netbeans/project/build/web/target/WEB-INF/resources/images/IMG_1996.jpg

Comment: I dont want put folder in WEB-INF that will change many things. I want keep src folder outside of WEB-INF.

Comment: make sure this directory gets deployed.

Comment: I dont need deploy src folder that is also one of the reason why I don't want keep src inside web-inf.

Comment: I wasn't referring to "src", "src" should contain the JAVA sources. I was referring to to the folder you keep the images in. if you want <img src=> to work, the image must reside with the deployed resources.

Comment: Now we go so far, the next problem is how convert system path to url, is there some function inside java API or I must do it through code.

Comment: I found solution and that is over URI class, URI.create(systempath);